# Weighted overlay in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to work on weighted overlay analysis in Google Earth Engine Python API. I have reclassified my layers and tryting to assign weights for each of my selected indicators. Getting errors. Could anybody suggest appropriate ways to do so.

Sample code:

```
overlay = image.expression(
    ('0.6 * slopereclass) + (0.4 * elevationreclass))', {
    'Slopereclass': image.select('slopereclass'),
    'elevationreclass': image.select('elevationreclass')   
    }))
``
where `slopereclass` is reclassified slope and `elevationreclss` is reclassified elevation.
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: EEException: Image.parseExpression, argument 'expression': Invalid type.
Expected type: String.
Actual type: List<Object>.
Actual value: [0.6 * slopereclass) + (0.4 * elevationreclass)), {Slopereclass=<Image<[constant]>>, elevationreclass=<Image<[constant_1]>>}]
@polygeo

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Your first quote is in the wrong place.  It should be outside the parentheses.

```
'(0.6 * slopereclass) + (0.4 * elevationreclass)'
```

Comment: stil getting the same error.  I am pasitng my whole codes here: I have two layers slope and elevation. I reclassified them and tyring to build a overlaid image: slopereclass  = ee.Image(1) \           .where(slope.gt(10).And(slope.lte(20)), 2) \           .where(slope.gt(20).And(slope.lte(30)), 3) \